# Change output dll name while compiling a library in mingw

Tags: c, dll, autotools

I am compiling opus library on windows using mingw/msys. I want to compile it for both 32 bit and 64 bit environments, so I want to have two dll files, with names something like `libopus32.dll` and `libopus64.dll`. In this way, I will be able to load the correct library in Java.
However, the `./configure && make && make install` procedure always produces `libopus-0.dll` file under bin directory.

I tried `--program-suffix=32` option, but it did not work.

I tried to change the the `configure.ac` file, and edited the `AC_INIT` directive, it did not work either.

Answer (score -1):

As I don't have enough reputation for commenting, I'll leave this here as an answer.

If I'm not mistaken, you need to have `MinGW-w64` installed, which will allow you to use `-m64` flag for 64-bit output. You can also specify `-m32` for 32-bit. At least this works when I compile my things via command line; I'm not sure if it's also applicable on compiling via `./configure`.

Comment: I already have two mingw environments, and can use -m32/-m64 bit flags. But the dll name is same in both case. They do not append 32/64 to the library name. Shortly, the question is not to compile in multiple environments, the question is "how to change output dll name".